# Style dialogPreference

Tags: android, android-theme

I've got a custom dialog preference with a seek bar. I want to apply a custom style but I'm not able to select the theme. After a bit of digging in the Android code, I see that in the `showDialog()` method of `DialogPreference`, the builder is called with default constructor, there is no way to change the theme because it's a final dialog field initialized only by constructor (there is no `setTheme()` method of dialog builder). How can I do?

Comment: `public DialogPreference (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)` I'm not sure but you might be able to provide the style using the 3rd parameter.

Comment: @ShivamVerma No, it doesn't work. Just tried.